# Lost Microstrategy Administrator Password?

Tags: microstrategy

In researching this scenario, all I could find was a suggestion that you contact Microstrategy, send them your metadata DB and ask them for the password.

This CAN'T be the only way.

Is there no way to simply reset the password in some fashion?  Looking at the DSSMDUSRACCT table in the metadata DB, this appears to hold (at first glance anyway) a hashed/encrypted password, but I don't believe this is correct, as every entry for every account is the same in the PASSWD field.

Can someone suggest an alternative beyond sending a database to Microstrategy?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any alternative. We ended up in similar scenario and had Microstrategy reset the password. Password is not easily recoverable from Medadata since it is secured.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how many projects you have in your metadata or if you have access to another user that may have all privileges; but another option would be to create a new database, use MSTR configuration wizard to populate metadata tables, then duplicate the project across project sources into the new metadata that was just created.  The Administrator user in this new metadata will have a blank password.  If this is not an option then I recommend to open a support ticket (as others have suggested).

Answer (score 1):

One of the things which one can try is to see any command manager script or system manager workflow. Every MicroStrategy environment may have atleast one of the above two things running in their environment. If you check the file, you may see the password for the administrator user. But in case if there is none of these being used then contacting MicroStrategy support would be the right thing to do.

Thanks,
Nikhil.

Answer (score 0):

Benedict's right, there's no way they would keep passwords in plaintext in the metadata. You'll have to send it to them in a support ticket. It can take quite a few days, but they get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

as soon as you get it reset use object manager, create a configuration object package for the administrator account and anytime you forget it, just redeploy the package to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the MicroStrategy Object Manager to copy the Administrator user from another project source/server to this environment.
This should do the trick if you have at least one other user with the right administrative privileges.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by having another user with administrative access (to disable/enable users)

Workstation UI should allow you to enable the admin user. Developer UI does not enable unlocking administrator users (unlike other accounts, this option will remain grayed out for administrators). However, you should be able to enable the admin user in Workstation UI or You need to give Metadata to Microstrategy.

Answer (score -1):

The other day I wanted to login to one of our applications. However, I forgot my username and password. I tried using the forgot password wizard but had no luck.

The steps I am about to walkthrough will work with most web applications with average logon security measures. It may not work with MicroStrategy, but should work if the input password is not externally verified.

So this is how I got access:

- First I logged into my database manager -If you don't have access to
  this... run a scan for 'password' on your server root. For Linux I
  write `sudo grep 'password' -roni` or try: db_pass, dbpass,
  database_password, etc as other search terms... The `-roni` will apply various filtering and
  options to the search... aka line number, file name and etc. After
  getting some results... find a likely file and open it to see if you
  have your database details in there.
- Login to your database manager. Find the table associated with your account. (This will usually have the name X_users If the password isn't hashed, just take it and login with it... if it is hashed... copy the hashed value to your clipboard.
- Change the directory to your chosen applications root.
- Run the scan with the search term 'password' or 'md5(' ...this will hopefully bring up a login controller file.
- Edit the line within the function that takes your login input. Change the value '`md5($#####)`' with '`$#####`', (aka removing the md5hashing of your input).
- Reload the login page. Now, enter your username and hashed password copied from the database and login.
- If done correctly you should now be logged into your web app.
- Change the password of the account. Now go back to the login controller file and undo the chnages.

This might not be applicable with your app in question, but it's worth a shot! ....and if it isn't appropriate for your scenario... it could still be very helpful for someone else with a similar problem and different application. I just thought there's a small chance it may help someone who's locked out of one of their web applications. Rather than having to reinstall and lose data.

I'd be happy for you to improve on this or give some feedback.